# Looping through a datalist on another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, findcontrol, datalistitem

I have a datalist on an ascx page called `shippingorders1` and I am trying to access the label called `lblGiftCodeAmount`. I am trying to loop through the datalist and retrieve the text of the label convert it to decimal and sum it. In a click event from my main page I have the following:

```
decimal addGiftCards = 0.0M;
foreach(DataListItem dli in (DataList)Page.FindControl("ShippingOrders1").FindControl("dlGiftCodeAmount").Items)
{
    addGiftCards += Convert.ToDecimal(((Label)dli.FindControl("lblGiftCodeAmount")).Text);
}
```

When this runs, I get a `NullReferenceException` on the line `addGiftCards+=` because of the label.
In my Immediate window when I type in:

```
(DataList)Page.FindControl("ShippingOrders1").FindControl("dlGiftCodeAmount").Items
```

It shows me everything I expect to see, but when I type `dli` it returns the `DataItem` as `null`. I loop through this exact same datalist on another page, and it gives me no problems. So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to get around this issue?

Any additional code need I will update the solution.

Comment: your not using the Loop Var (dli) anywhere in the loop? and whats (Shippingorders1)?

Comment: @wizpert thanks for the catch, I had tried something else and forgot to switch it back before copying my code. Above code is updated

Answer (score 0):

DataItem is only available on initial page load; afterward, the data is kept through viewstate and DataItem is not available.  It's only available again on rebind.  Also, Items may also contain any header or footer you may have too, so FindControl wouldn't find a control in a different template.